# Creating nested lists in a loop in R

Tags: r

This bit of code does what I want it to do, but generates a warning for every iteration of the loop:

```
library(epiR)
    cccList <- list()
    for (i in 3:ncol(dfData)){
      tmpvar <- paste("cccIntactVs.", i, sep = "")
      assign(
        tmpvar, 
        epi.ccc(
          dfData[2:nrow(dfData),2], 
          dfData[2:nrow(dfData),i], 
          ci = "z-transform", 
          conf.level = 0.95, 
          rep.measure = FALSE
        )
      )
      cccList[i] <- get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i))
    }
```

I get this warning every time the output of epi.ccc() is added to cccList():

```
Warning in cccList[i] <- get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Is there a more proper way of accomplishing this? The output of epi.ccc() is a list of 7 elements. Since the output is the same length each time and I'm only adding to the list, why is it complaining about mismatched lengths or replacement?

Comment: If it really and truly works, you could use `suppressWarnings`. An R warning is based on heuristics, and those heuristics are not infallible.

Comment: Side note: I find code that uses `assign` to add variables to an environment like this to seem clunky and hard to extend well. You might do better to keep the data stored in a `list`: one benefit is that if you find yourself applying a function to each of the created variables, when in a list you can simply do `lapply(list_of_epiccc, myfunc)` in one fell-swoop (instead of `myfunc(epiccc1); myfunc(epiccc2); myfunc(epiccc3);`).

Comment: `cccList[i] <- get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i))` is equivalent to `cccList[i] <- get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i))[1]` as far as I can tell, it should remove the warning, but it seems you're doing something wrong

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks. That does remove the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `[[i]]` instead of `[i]`

Basically, `[` means you want to replace a certain **part** of a list with different content, and the replacement needs to have just as many items as the number of slots you are trying to replace.
OTOH, using `[[` means you want to put everything you are assigning into one slot, which it seems you want to do.
An example of what happens:

```
myList <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
myList[3:5] <- c(11, 12, 13)
myList[[6]] <- c(14, 15, 16)
```

Here, 11-13 are distributed among slots 3 through 5: 3 replacement items in 3 slots.
And 14-16 are placed in one slot: This slot now contains a length-3 vector.
Now what happens if we try this?

```
myList[1] <- c(17,18,19)
```

We tell R it should distribute 3 items over one slot. It tries the best it can, which is not much: it discards everything but the first item. But luckily it warns you. If you really just want to assign just the first item, you can use

```
myList[1] <- c(17,18,19)[1]
```

But that's not really useful, there's no use in supplying 18 and 19.
You could make it a list of length one:

```
myList[1] <- list(c(17,18,19))
```

But generally, if you want to put it in one slot, using `[[` is the way to go.

And as a sidetrack: why was it build this way?
The reason is that `[` can give you access to multiple slots, and you might not know which ones or how many beforehand. What should happen if I try this?

```
someVar <- readLines(somefile) # someVar happens to be c(1, 2) instead of having length 1
myList[someVar] <- 21:23
```

Put 21:23 in both slots? Put 21 in the first slot and the rest (22, 23) in slot 2?
Using `[[` means you are sure only one slot is used, and you're not unexpectedly overwriting anything.

Answer (score 0):

`cccList[i] <- get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i))` will trigger this warning if `get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i))` is not of length 1.

Using `get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i))[1]` should solve it but if you didn't expect `get(paste0("cccIntactVs.", i))` to have a length superior to 1 you likely have a mistake somewhere else in your code, despite the result looking fine to you now.